# Can the chat interface also offer us the user's profile from the chat room's site?

Tags: feature-request, chat

When I click on a user's name or gravatar in the chat interface, I get a popup with a number of options.  The top two are always:

- user profile
- user profile on (`<chat user's parent site>`)

Frequently, though, I need to access the user's profile on the site the *room* belongs to.

For instance, on [The Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), someone might ask a question about their profile on Gaming.  If their parent user isn't a Gaming user, though, I can't get directly to their Gaming profile from the chat interface.  I have to either go to the Gaming site and find them, or I have to click through to their parent profile and then look through the associated accounts to find their account on the site.

Is there some way to get a third entry in this list, which would link directly to the user's profile on the site *that owns the chat room,* if such a site and profile exists?

Answer (score 5):

As I mention [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127988/what-is-the-point-of-the-parent-user-in-chat/127993#127993), we're planning to move the "parent user" idea more to the background. It's not yet clear what precisely we're going to change around here, but I imagine it being based around these two concepts:

- Your chat.se account is attached to your *network* account, not a particular site account. In your case, your chat parent user would be [Stack Exchange user 1026765](https://stackexchange.com/users/1026765/agent86), not [gaming.se user 13845](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/13845/agent86).

  We may (but this is one of the areas that still has to be looked at) still have the notion of a "main" site account in some way or the other, but it will be less important and less prominent than it is at the moment.
- In a particular room, users should be considered more in the context of the *room's* parent site, not the *user's* (of course with some sort of fallback for the case that the room isn't attached to a particular site, like [The Assembly](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2691/the-assembly), or that the user doesn't have an account on the rooms site).

  This is where your request comes in – in fact, I would argue that [Tim's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125791/can-the-chat-interface-also-offer-us-the-users-profile-from-the-chat-rooms-sit/132918#132918) makes sense; in a chemistry.se chat room, the most important site account is the Chemistry account.

Once again, not all details of these changes are drawn out yet, but big picture-wise, they will indeed (at least to an extent) include what you're requesting.

Comment: From Laura's edit I understand it's not planned for immediate action anymore, but any update nonetheless?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, why not remove the parent user link completely? I don't really think it's that useful. On Chem.SE chat, I want to see the chem.SE profiles of the users. I don't *care* about their profiles elsewhere. Since the parent user site favicon is shown on the usercard anyway, why not link it to the parent user site profile? That way, a more useful link is up front, and a less useful one is kept, but made less prominent.

Current (on [chem.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table)):

[image]

Proposed:

[image]