# Why chat profile in some rooms does not have a parent SE profile?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, network-profile

When in SO rooms, everything seems to be normal. But when in DBA.stackexchange rooms, like [The-Heap](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap), (@Ben Brocka noticed that) my chat profile does not seem to have a parent SE profile and shows not two links, like other users, but **only one link**:

[image]

Notice that other users in that room show fine and so does my profile in SO chat rooms:

[image] [image]

Is that a bug on SE-chat code or I can correct this somehow?

Comment: Iiiinteresting... I'm looking.

Comment: So, when it does display it, it displays the wrong site? There must be some other criteria for determining what link gets shown there on the SE chat.

Comment: Looks like you don't have a parent site on chat.SE http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/9016/ypercube. I even used the "refresh profile from parent site" mod button, and it said "refreshing profile failed".

Comment: @TimManishEarth : So, what can I do?

Comment: @ypercube: Seems to have fixed itself. I've set your parent profile to DBA (change it if you like).

Comment: Aah, balpha fixed it.

Comment: I forgot to bring this up, I meant to as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The API had some hickups last night and returned broken data when refreshing your account (you basically had user id 0 on all your sites). This kind of issue will be self-correcting once the changes to the parent user handling are done (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127988/what-is-the-point-of-the-parent-user-in-chat/127993#127993) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125791/can-the-chat-interface-also-offer-us-the-users-profile-from-the-chat-rooms-sit/133595#133595)), but currently, this requires dev intervention.

I have intervened :)

Comment: Yes, it's fixed now. Thnx.

Comment: The issue re-appeared again. I noticed yesterday but it may have been there longer.