# My chat profile is no longer linked to any profile on any parent site

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

[My chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/37906/al-ummat) isn't showing my parent SE profile. [Possibly related to this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134433/why-chat-profile-in-some-rooms-does-not-have-a-parent-se-profile).  My intention is to report this as error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed now. Since this has happened a few times recently, I have added some logging for cases where the API returns bogus data, so we can possibly get to the bottom of the problem. I have also added functionality for accounts with data that is broken in a way like yours was to be recovered automatically in the future (and in fact successfully tested this functionality with your user account).